# How does padding work when using a pytorch TransformerEncoder?

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model, self-attention

I'm trying to make a TransformerEncoder work with variable length sequences. I understand I can pass a `src_key_padding_mask` to the `forward` method.

Here's some example code.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

embedding_dim = 4
num_heads = 1
ff_dim = 16

encoder = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(
        d_model=embedding_dim,
        nhead=num_heads,
        dim_feedforward=ff_dim,
        batch_first=True
    )

input_tensor = torch.randn(3, 6, embedding_dim)
input_tensor[0,5,:] = 0
input_tensor[0,4,:] = 0
input_tensor[1,5,:] = 0
print(f"input\n{input_tensor}")

print(f"no mask\n{encoder(input_tensor)}")

bool_src_key_padding_mask = torch.tensor(
        [[False, False, False, False, True, True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, True],
         [False, False, False, False, False, False]])

print(f"mask\n{encoder(input_tensor, src_key_padding_mask=bool_src_key_padding_mask)}")
```

I would expect the result of the last line to print out a tensor containing padding tokens (`0` in this case), but it doesn't. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`src_key_padding_mask` causes the masked items to contribute nothing to the attention calculation for the other items in the sequence. It does not stop computation on the masked inputs. Such is the nature of GPUs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Karl. So I should ignore the calculations for the masked items, e.g. by using the same mask over the output?